# How to break out of a for and try loop moment my code work?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, try-catch

I have a try loop that executes a post function which takes some time to work:

```
def recalc_proj(proj):
    for x in range(0,10):
        while True:
            try:
                newproj = proj.post('docs/recalc')
            except someError:
                print "another job is running. waiting 10s"
                time.sleep(10)
                continue
            break
        print "SUCCESS"
```

i only want to run `newproj = proj.post('docs/recalc')` once and if it runs without error, quit.

However, after running the function above, i get this output on the screen:

```
another job is running. waiting 10s
another job is running. waiting 10s
another job is running. waiting 10s
another job is running. waiting 10s
SUCCESS
another job is running. waiting 10s
another job is running. waiting 10s
another job is running. waiting 10s
```

Why does it continue looping even after the line of code i need successfully runs? i thought the break means to get out of the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `break` statement terminates the current loop, which is the `while` loop in your example. You can put another `break` after your `print` statement to terminate the `for` loop as well:

```
 ...
 print "SUCCESS"
 break
```